# How to set the last path as the next default using JFileChooser

Tags: java, path, directory, jfilechooser

I have several dialog boxes which provide a File Chooser. For the first, my coding was like this

```
JFileChooser chooser= new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        int returnVal= chooser.showOpenDialog(this);

        if(returnVal==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            File f= chooser.getSelectedFile();
            jTextField1.setText(f.getPath());
            chooser.setCurrentDirectory(f);
        }
```

In my case, i would like to set the last path which is selected as the default path in next selection JFileChooser. Is there any solution for me?
Thanks for any response

Comment: I think you will have to write the "current" path to a file before closing your program.. Then the next time, read the path from the file and use it. This is just an approach and many might say its wrong.. :)

Comment: `chooser.setSelectedFile` will set the "currently selected file" to whatever `File` you give it.  But saving the previously selected file is something you'll have to handle yourself, as WhoAmI implied.  I don't think `JFileChooser` does that for you, unless I've missed something.

Comment: Are you looking for this default path to be retained after you have closed your application and restarted it?

Comment: @WhoAmI : I read some recommendations to try `setCurrentDirectory()` but i haven't done it yet. @ajb : If `JFileChooser` is not the right way, so what kind of way that i must take? @Jbueno : Yes. Do you have any suggestion for me? Thanks

Comment: @syaloom - MadProgrammer has shown it for you ..

Answer (score 6):

Depending on your requirements, you can use Preferences to store it away and use it again after the program has been restarted.

```
 Preferences pref = Preferences.userRoot();

// Retrieve the selected path or use
// an empty string if no path has
// previously been selected
String path = pref.get("DEFAULT_PATH", "");

JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);

// Set the path that was saved in preferences
chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(path));

int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
{
    File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(f);

    // Save the selected path
    pref.put("DEFAULT_PATH", f.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You will have to "remember" the last path.

This can easily be done by storing the value in a instance variable...

```
private File lastPath;
//...
lastPath = f.getParentFile();
```

And simply resetting it when you need to...

```
//...
if (lastPath != null) {
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(lastPath);
}
```

You could also use a single instance of the `JFileChooser`, so each time you show it, it will be at the last location it was used...